# multi select not work in cakephp.how can add all select?

Tags: database, cakephp, select

i create two multi select list in my cakephp view .
in one of select box get all users and in anouther get all car list .
i want select users and car name and insert in user profile.but just select one and last item .

my table=>

user -->
-id
-username
-user_family

car-->
-id
-name
-model

my controller{

```html
        $users = $this->User->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('User.id', 'User.username', 'User.user_family')));
        $this->set('users', $users);
        $cars = $this->Car->find('all', array());
        $this->set('cars', $cars);
```

}
and my view file {

```html
foreach($users as $user){
?>
    <option
        value="<?php echo $user['User']['id'] ?>"><?php echo $user['User']['username'].' (' .$user['User']['user_family']. ' )' ?></option>
    <?php
}

?></select>
<label>نام درس</label>    </label>
    <select name="car_id" id="car_id" multiple="true" style="width: 150px;height: 200px;">
    <?php
    foreach($cars as $car) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $car['Car']['id'] ?>"><?php echo $course['Car']['name'] ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select></fieldset>
```

}

and my pr() result:

```html
Array
(
    [user_id] => 16
    [car_id] => 8
)
```

but i select 10 user and 2 car .how can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try in controller

```
$users = $this->User->find('list');
$cars = $this->Car->find('list');

$this->set(compact('users','cars'));
```

in your view use Form helper

```
echo $this->Form->input('User');
echo $this->Form->input('Car');
```